# Get stack trace while debugging memory leak using windbg

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, heap-memory, windbg, stack-trace

I am following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31382/Memory-Leak-Detection-Using-Windbg) link to debug memory leak using windbg.

I have created a program,

### Leakstudy.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    while (a)
    {
        cin >> a;
        Sleep(1000);
        char* data = new char[2020]; //leak created
        cout << "leaked\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

### Debugging

1. **After building, run the exe directly and attached windbg.**
2. Given the symbol path image path and source path as given below

> ************* Path validation summary ************** Response                         Time (ms)     Location
> OK D:\C++\Workspace\examples\Leakstudy\x64\Debug
> Deferred srv*
>
> ************* Path validation summary ************** Response                         Time (ms)     Location
> OK D:\C++\Workspace\examples\Leakstudy\x64\Debug
> Deferred SRV*d:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
> OK D:\C++\Workspace\examples\Leakstudy\Leakstudy\x64\Debug
> Deferred srv*
>
> ************* Path validation summary ************** Response                         Time (ms)     Location
> OK D:\C++\Workspace\examples\Leakstudy\Leakstudy
> OK D:\C++\Workspace\examples\Leakstudy

3. Run the command `!heap -s`

[image]

4. Created leaks and run the same command again.

[image]

Identified the heap location `000001b606f50000`  is increasing. found the leak.

5. collected more information about leak using `!heap -stat -h 000001b606f50000`

[image]

Identified that the `7e4`  sized blocks are increasing (done it by running the above several times for different number of leaks)

6. get the allocations of that particular size blocks by `!heap -flt s 7e4`

[image]

1. Now the issue is while collecting the stack trace for the leak using `!heap -p -a 000001b606f52520` it is not showing any information

[image]

No stack trace is found.

Comment: Please don't post code as images. WinDbg allows copying text

Comment: Have you used `gflags` to enable the user stack trace database? Can you show the result of `!gflag` in your debugging session, please?